# ¿Cómo predecir dos variables continuas en una ANN?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, redes-neuronales

Estoy intentando crear una red neuronal que sea capaz de predecir dos variables continuas de salida con unas variables de entrada.
Para ello he realizado el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from numpy import asarray
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Importar el data set
mis_datos = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx')
mis_datos = mis_datos.to_dict("list")
x_vals = np.transpose(np.array([mis_datos['E_Core_cuad'], mis_datos['E_Fib_Cap_cuad'], mis_datos['E_Theta_cuad']]))
y1_vals = np.transpose(np.array([mis_datos['Ecore']]))
y2_vals = np.transpose(np.array([mis_datos['Eplaca']]))
y_vals = np.transpose((y1_vals[:,0],y2_vals[:,0]))


# Dividir el data set en conjunto de entrenamiento y conjunto de testing

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_vals, y_vals, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)


# Escalado de variables
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

# Inicializar la ANN

my_ANN = Sequential()
my_ANN.add(Dense(units = 269, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation ="relu", input_dim = 3))
#añdimos una segunda capa oculta
my_ANN.add(Dense(units = 200, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation ="relu"))
my_ANN.add(Dense(units = 150, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation ="relu"))
my_ANN.add(Dense(units = 100, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation ="relu"))
my_ANN.add(Dense(units = 50, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation ="relu"))
my_ANN.add(Dense(units = 40, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation ="relu"))
my_ANN.add(Dense(units = 30, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation ="relu"))
my_ANN.add(Dense(units = 10, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation ="relu"))

my_ANN.add(Dense(units = 2, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation ="relu"))

my_ANN.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

my_ANN.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 15, epochs=1100)

#Predecir variables
yhat = my_ANN.predict(X_test).round()
print(yhat)
print(y_test)
```

Según entiendo, la ultima capa de la red neuronal la he puesto como Dense units = 2, para que pueda predecir dos variables.

El problema es que cuando realizo la predicción con my_ANN.predict solo me predice una de las variables y la otra la deja a cero.

```
[[ 89.   0.]
 [108.   0.]
 [ 87.   0.]
 [250.   0.]
 [211.   0.]
 [  1.   0.]
 [321.   0.]
 [272.   0.]
 [107.   0.]
 [318.   0.]
 [130.   0.]
 [111.   0.]
 [398.   0.]
 [191.   0.]
 [363.   0.]
 [208.   0.]
 [380.   0.]
 [230.   0.]
 [  1.   0.]
 [320.   0.]
 [230.   0.]
 [107.   0.]
 [130.   0.]
 [210.   0.]
 [110.   0.]
 [150.   0.]
 [342.   0.]
 [110.   0.]
 [362.   0.]
 [362.   0.]
 [294.   0.]
 [190.   0.]
 [152.   0.]
 [398.   0.]
 [342.   0.]
 [ 65.   0.]
 [295.   0.]
 [296.   0.]
 [362.   0.]
 [ 46.   0.]
 [229.   0.]
 [130.   0.]
 [170.   0.]
 [363.   0.]
 [  1.   0.]
 [211.   0.]
 [  2.   0.]
 [170.   0.]
 [ 44.   0.]
 [149.   0.]
 [343.   0.]
 [249.   0.]
 [251.   0.]
 [296.   0.]]
```

¿Alguien sabe lo que está pasando o tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

La configuración de tu red neuronal es correcta, por lo que los fallos pueden venir de:

1. Comprobar que el **pre-procesado de datos** es correcto, es decir que le estás entregando los datos como quieres a la red neuronal, y cada dato se corresponde al inicial y tiene las dimensiones correctas.
2. No sé las pruebas que habrás hecho, pero siempre puedes **variar los hiper-parametros y las capas**, para ver que arquitectura te da mejores resultados, por ejemplo usar menos capas (2 o 3), usar el **error absolut medio** (MAE) como función de error, menos epocas (50 por ejemplo), otro **batch size** (64 por ejemplo), etc.
3. Por último veo que redondeas los resultados de tu predicción con `round()` puede que tu segunda variable predicha esté dando unos resultados cercanos a cero, y te creas que son cero, porque lo estás redondeando.

Como conclusión te puedo decir dos cosas:

1. Tu arquitectura de Red Neuronal **es correcta**, no tienes ningún fallo.
2. **No por tener más capas densas, y más epocas tienes una mejor red neuronal**, hay que hacer pruebas y buscar la arquitectura adecuada.